# How to stop on after first failure while checking notnull and have custom/must for a field using fluent valdiation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

```
    Along with null error message, even the custom/must validation is ran and error failure is displayed. 

    I have set globally ValidatorOptions.CascadeMode = CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure;
    Inside Custom can check if(motor = null) return; But is there any other way to restrict not to run custom or must validation in fluent validator.

Below is my PersonDetails model class :
    Public Class PersonDetails {
     public PersonName {get;set;}
    }

    Public Class PersonName {
     public string Firstname {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    }


    public class PersonApplicantValidator : AbstractValidator<PersonDetails>
    {
                        RuleFor(x => x.PersonName ).NotNull().WithMessage("Mandatory field").Custom(
                            (personName, context) =>
                            {

                                if(personName.Firstname == null)
                                    context.AddFailure("FirstName is mandatory");
                            });

             }
```

When PersonName= null,
    Actual : Mandatory field FirstName is mandatory

```
Expected : Mandatory field
```

How to stop on first failure and not run custom?

Comment: Probably you need conditions: https://fluentvalidation.net/start#conditions

Comment: Also it's possible to set a cascading mode to stop further validation after the first failure: https://fluentvalidation.net/start#setting-the-cascade-mode

Comment: Could you please illustrate it with an example? I am new to fluent validation.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make `FirstName` mandatory only when `Name` is empty you can use this:

```
RuleFor(x => x.FirstName)
     .NotNull().When(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Name)).WithMessage("FirstName is mandatory");
```